# Create indicator for two highest observations?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame:

```
Month      Week   Y     Name   Color
January     2     1.2    Joe    Red
January     2     3.3    Eric   Red
January     2     4.5    Mike   Blue
January     2     1.7    Brian  Blue
January     2     2.9    Pete   Red
January     3     4.6    Joe    Red
January     3     5.1    Eric   Blue
January     3     2.1    Mike   Blue
January     3     6.9    Pete   Red
...
```

I would like to create a new column ('Highest') which identifies the individuals with the two highest Y values in a given week (identifying them with A and B so it will be easier to create line segments later in my project) who also have the color 'Blue'.

```
Month      Week   Y     Name    Highest
January     2     1.2    Joe       -
January     2     3.3    Eric      B
January     2     4.5    Mike      A
January     2     1.7    Brian     -
January     2     2.9    Pete      -
January     3     4.6    Joe       -
January     3     5.1    Eric      B
January     3     2.1    Mike      A
January     3     6.9    Pete      -
...
```

Additionally, as you can see in the table above, I want the 'Highest' column to be the same throughout the entire month--the column should show individuals with the highest two Y values in week 2 for all observations in a given month. I'm assuming this will require `group_by(Month, Week)  %>%`

Comment: That's unclear, Week numbers aren't actually the week-numbers of a year, are they?

Comment: @jay.sf they're the week-numbers of the month. I only have weeks 2-4, no week 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `arrange` the data by `Y` values and assign `'A'`, `'B'` to first two values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Month, Week, desc(Y)) %>%
  group_by(Month, Week) %>%
  mutate(Highest = c('A', 'B', rep(NA, n()-2)))
  #If you want to have '-' instead of `NA`. 
  #mutate(Highest = c('A', 'B', rep('-', n()-2)))
```

Comment: how would it be possible to add another condition to this, ie: how to indicate the two highest observations in each group who also have the color Blue?

Comment: That would not be an easy fix to the above answer. It would be better if you ask that as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350890/how-to-indicate-two-highest-observations-in-group-with-two-conditions

Comment: my apologies, I had upvoted it but forgotten to accept. Sorry!